# State handling on KeyedCoProcessFunction serving ML models

Tags: apache-flink

I am working on a KeyedCoProcessFunction that looks like this:

```scala
class MyOperator extends KeyedCoProcessFunction[String, ModelDef, Data, Prediction]
  with CheckpointedFunction {

  // To hold loaded models
  @transient private var models: HashMap[(String, String), Model] = _

  // For serialization purposes
  @transient private var modelsBytes: MapState[(String, String), Array[Bytes]] = _

  ...

  override def snapshotState(context: FunctionSnapshotContext): Unit = {
    modelsBytes.clear() // This raises an exception when there is no active key set
    for ((k, model) <- models) {
      modelsBytes.put(k, model.toBytes(v))
    }
  }

  override def initializeState(context: FunctionInitializationContext): Unit = {
    modelsBytes = context.getKeyedStateStore.getMapState[String, String](
      new MapStateDescriptor("modelsBytes", classOf[String], classOf[String])
    )

    if (context.isRestored) {
      // restore models from modelsBytes
    }
  }

}
```

The state consists of a collection of ML models built using a third party library. Before checkpoints, I need to dump the loaded models into byte arrays in `snapshotState`.

My question is, within `snapshotState`, `modelsBytes.clear()` raises an exception when there is no active key. This happens when I start the application from scratch without any data on the input streams. So, when the time for a checkpoint comes, I get this error:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: No key set. This method should not be called outside of a keyed context.`

However, when the input stream contains data, checkpoints work just fine. I am a bit confused about this because `snapshotState` does not provide a keyed context (contrary to `processElement1` and `processElement2`, where the current key is accessible by doing `ctx.getCurrentKey`) so it seems to me that the calls to `clear` and `put` within `snapshotState` should fail always since they're supposed to work only within a keyed context. Can anyone clarify if this is the expected behaviour actually?

Answer (score 1):

A keyed state can only be used on a keyed stream as written in the documentation.

```
 * <p>The state is only accessible by functions applied on a {@code KeyedStream}. The key is
 * automatically supplied by the system, so the function always sees the value mapped to the
 * key of the current element. That way, the system can handle stream and state partitioning
 * consistently together.
```

If you call `clear()`, you will **not** clear the whole map, but just reset the state of the current key. The key is always known in `processElementX`.

```
/**
 * Removes the value mapped under the current key.
 */
void clear();
```

You should actually receive a better exception when you try to call `clear` in a function other than `processElementX`. In the end, you are using the keyed state incorrectly.

Now for your actual problem. I'm assuming you are using a `KeyedCoProcessFunction` because the models are updated in a separate input. If they are static, you could just load them `open` from a static source (for example, included in the jar). Furthermore, often there is only one model that is applied for all values with different keys, then you could use `BroadCast` state. So I'm assuming you have different models for different types of data separated by keys.

If they are coming in from input2, then you already serialize them upon invocation of `processElement2`.

```
override def processElement2(model: Model, ctx: Context, collector): Unit = {
    models.put(ctx.getCurrentKey, model)
    modelsBytes.put(ctx.getCurrentKey, model.toBytes(v))
}
```

Then you would not override `snapshotState`, as the state is already up-to-date. `initializeState` would deserialize models eagerly or you could also materialize them lazily in `processElement1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Arvid. Your assumption is correct, I am using different models for different types of data separated by keys. As for your suggestion on serializing the models in `processElement2` and do not override `snapshotState`, that could be an option. The problem is that my models hold its own data state that changes as they process data (sent from `processElement1`). That is why I need to serialize them before each checkpoint, and I think the only place for doing that would be `snapshotState`. What about doing a simple check like this: ```if (models.nonEmpty) modelsBytes.clear(); ... {```.

Comment: I guess another option could be to use operator state (instead of keyed state)...and keep an state per operator instance instead of by key...I guess I could implement it like this and that would still serve my purposes.

Comment: Regarding your observation: "You should actually receive a better exception when you try to call clear in a function other than processElementX. In the end, you are using the keyed state incorrectly". Note that I can indeed call clear, put etc within `snapshotState` once I have received some data and there is an active key. For example, if I do a simple check like this first `if (models.nonEmpty) modelsBytes.clear(); ... }` the `clear` call works just fine and resets the state of the current key....I understand from your words that this is not the expected behaviour, maybe a bug?

Comment: Ah if you model changes then you are right, keep as it. I'd probably remove the clear completely and just overwrite the entries. How often do you need to remove a model?

Comment: Regarding that `clear` actually works in certain circumstances that is a bug to me. It should never work. There is no key for `snapshotState`, but `clear` needs to have a contextual key. My guess is that the key is not reset in this case.

Comment: I won't normally remove a model, but it is something I have to support, it will happen less frequently compared to adding/updating models but it will also happen. If using `clear` is dangerous (or inherently wrong) I could just remove the models in `processElement2` when I detect a model somehow marked for deletion (since in this case I no longer need to keep track of its own state).

Comment: I'd probably go for tombstone records (= null value, or any specific marker) as you would do when you'd use Kafka.

Comment: For the record, I got some additional replies on the [Flink user mailing list](http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/Using-MapState-clear-put-methods-in-snapshotState-within-KeyedCoProcessFunction-valid-or-not-tp31353.html).

Comment: It is still not clear to me whether serializing the (keyed state) models within `snapshotState` makes any sense at all. If being allowed to use `clear` there looks like a bug, shouldn't it so, for the same reason, to use `put` for updating the map state? Without a keyed context being passed, how can I know which key I am working on? Which guarantees do I have that I will be able to recover from a snapshot in case of failure? Indeed, I have verified that checkpoints taken like that cannot be recovered properly from time time, getting an empty map state on restore.